# How to open web urls using C language?

Tags: c, url, browser

I know the function `system("START www.weburl.com")`.
However, I need to change link during program running and open different parts of that website.
I have to add to that link, for example, `www.weburl.com/i`, where `i` is my integer.

I can not do it manually every time, so my question is how can I open webpages based on my strings from the program?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new string that uses the number you want, then call `system` on that:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void open_website_part(int i) {
    char *cmd;
    asprintf(&cmd, "START www.weburl.com/%d", i);
    system(cmd);
    free(cmd);
}
```

Or if your libc doesn't have `asprintf` available:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FORMAT_STRING "START www.weburl.com/%d"
void open_website_part(int i) {
    size_t len = snprintf(NULL, 0, FORMAT_STRING, i) + 1;
    char *cmd = malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    snprintf(cmd, len, FORMAT_STRING, i);
    system(cmd);
    free(cmd);
}
```

Comment: I got the error:asprintf was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Did you use `#define _GNU_SOURCE` first and then `#include <stdio.h>` after it? If not, do that. If so, then your system may not have it, in which case you can do the same thing manually with 2 passes of regular sprintf.

Comment: Yes,I am on windows if that changes something.